# Is there a shorter way to call a generic non-static method of an object?

Tags: c++

I have a class:

```
class Handler {
public:
      virtual void m1(const std::string &);
      virtual void m2(const std::string &);
      virtual void m3(const std::string &);
};
```

I'm going to have a vector of these guys. These are handlers for various actions from a REST server. I'm going to do code like this:

```
void gotActionM1(const std::string &msg) {
     for (const Handler &hander: handlers) {
          handler.m1(msg);
     }
}
```

I have to reproduce that code for each of the actions, and so far I have about 15. It might grow. I could do this instead:

```
void gotActionM1(const std::string &msg) {
     forAllHandlers( [&](const Handler &handler) { handler.m1(msg); );
}
```

Or I think I can do something like this:

```
void gotActionM1(const std::string &msg) {
     forAllHandlers( &Handler::m1, this, msg );
}
```

I'm not sure the second one will work given that it's virtual. And I'm not quite sure of the syntax when writing forAllHandlers() in this case. It's a std::function. I might need a std::bind in here. I think it becomes ugly.

Is there a shorter way. For instance:

```
     forAllHandlers( &Handler::m1, msg );
```

My example is only 3 lines, so that's not so bad, but in actuality, it's about 6 or 8 lines, and the only difference is calling m1 or m2. That's a lot of annoying cut and paste.

Right now, the lambda mode is probably my best choice. It just seems weird to use a lambda when I just want to pass a function pointer. If it were static functions, it would be trivial.

Comment: Should any responses to this assume there always exists some container `handlers` containing references to all existing and/or desirable `Handler` instances as your `gotActionM1` seems to suggest?

Comment: JFYI playing with lambdas sometimes hurts performance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your requirements. Is the following code what you want?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Handler
{
public:
    virtual void m1(const std::string &) = 0;
    virtual void m2(const std::string &) = 0;
    virtual void m3(const std::string &) = 0;
    virtual ~Handler() = default;
};

class Foo
{
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Handler>> handlers_;

public:
    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    void addHandler(Args&&... args)
    {
        handlers_.push_back(std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

    void gotAction(const std::string &msg, decltype(&Handler::m1) action)
    {
        for (auto &handler : handlers_)
            std::invoke(action, handler, msg);
    }
};

class Handler1 : public Handler
{
public:
    virtual void m1(const std::string &msg) override { std::cout << "Handle1 m1:" << msg << std::endl; }
    virtual void m2(const std::string &msg) override { std::cout << "Handle1 m2:" << msg << std::endl; }
    virtual void m3(const std::string &msg) override { std::cout << "Handle1 m3:" << msg << std::endl; }
};

class Handler2 : public Handler
{
private:
    std::string name_;
    int flag_;
public:
    Handler2(std::string name, int flag):name_(std::move(name)), flag_(flag) {};
    virtual void m1(const std::string &msg) override { std::cout << "Handle2: m1 " << name_ << flag_ << msg << std::endl; }
    virtual void m2(const std::string &msg) override { std::cout << "Handle2: m2" << name_ << flag_ << msg << std::endl; }
    virtual void m3(const std::string &msg) override { std::cout << "Handle2: m3" << name_ << flag_ << msg << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.addHandler<Handler1>();
    foo.addHandler<Handler2>("puppy", 100);
    foo.gotAction("hello", &Handler::m1);
    foo.gotAction("hello", &Handler::m3);
    foo.gotAction("hello", &Handler::m2);
}
```